# Custom address attribute: issue on display value magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, customer-attribute, customer-address

I have created a custom attribute for customer address. I can see the attribute on admin, I can insert value on frontend, the value saved successfully (and it displayed in address preview) however if I try to edit the address, no value appears.

This is my code. I will appreciate any help.

> Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Block\Customer\Address\Form\Edit\Comment.php

```
<?php

namespace Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Block\Customer\Address\Form\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Comment extends Template
{
    /** @var AddressInterface */
    private $address;
    /** @var AddressRepositoryInterface */
    private $addressRepository;
    /** @var AddressInterfaceFactory */
    private $addressFactory;
    /** @var Session */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * Comment Constructor
     * @param Template|Context $context
     * @param AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param AddressInterfaceFactory $addressFactory
     * @param Session $session
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressFactory,
        Session $session,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $session;
    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $addressId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        if ($addressId) {
            try {
                $this->address = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);
                if ($this->address->getCustomerId() != $this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                    $this->address = null;
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
                $this->address = null;
            }
        }
        if (null === $this->address)
            $this->address = $this->addressFactory->create();

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {

        $customWidgetBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Block\Customer\Widget\Comment'
        );

        $customWidgetBlock->setAddress($this->address);

        return $customWidgetBlock->toHtml();
    }
}
```

> Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Block\Customer\Widget\Comment.php

```
<?php

namespace Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Block\Customer\Widget;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Comment extends Template
{
    /** @var AddressMetadataInterface  */
    private $addressMetadata;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('widget/comment.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Comment constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param AddressMetadataInterface $addressMetadata
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        AddressMetadataInterface $addressMetadata,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->addressMetadata = $addressMetadata;
    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isRequired()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute()
            ? $this->getAttribute()->isRequired()
            : false;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFieldId()
    {
        return 'comment';
    }

    /**
     * @return Phrase|string
     */
    public function getFieldLabel()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute()
            ? $this->getAttribute()->getFrontendLabel()
            : __('Comment');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFieldName()
    {
        return 'comment';
    }

    public function getSortOrder()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute()->getSortOrder();
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        /** @var AddressInterface $address */
        $address = $this->getAddress();
        if ($address instanceof AddressInterface) {
            return $address->getCustomAttribute('comment')
                ? $address->getCustomAttribute('comment')->getValue()
                : null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private function getAttribute()
    {
        try {
            $attribute = $this->addressMetadata->getAttributeMetadata('comment');
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
            $attribute = null;
        }

        return $attribute;
    }
}
```

> Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Plugin\Customer\AddressEditPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Plugin\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class AddressEditPlugin
{

    /** @var LayoutInterface */
    private $layout;

    public function __construct(
        LayoutInterface $layout
    )
    {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit $edit
     * @param $result
     * @return string
     */
    public function afterGetNameBlockHtml(
        \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit $edit,
        $result
    )
    {
        $customBlock = $this->layout->createBlock(
            'Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Block\Customer\Address\Form\Edit\Comment',
            'sandy_address_custom_attributes_comment'
        );

        return $result . $customBlock->toHtml();
    }
}
```

> view/frontend/templates/widget/comment.phtml

```
<?php /** @var \Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Block\Customer\Widget\Comment $block */ ?>
<div class="field comment <?php if($block->isRequired()) echo ' required'; echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getSortOrder());?>">
    <label class="label" for="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFieldId()); ?>">
        <span>
            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFieldLabel()); ?>
        </span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text"
            id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFieldId()); ?>"
            name="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFieldName()); ?>"
            value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getValue()); ?>"
            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFieldLabel()); ?>"
            class="input-text"
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFieldParams()); ?>
            <?php if($block->isRequired()) echo 'data-validate="{required:true}"' ?> 
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

> Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Setup\InstallData

```
<?php


namespace Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'comment', [
            'label' => 'Comment',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'type' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'position' => 1001,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'comment')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this attribute as extension  attribute using below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="comment" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

this code, will be written at `Sandy\AddressCustomAttributes\etc\extension_attributes.xml`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still doesn't work.